# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The entity must not be null

Tags: java, spring

My method return this exception below

```
@Transactional
default
void deleteAndSaveList(List< myObject > listofObject){
   this.deleteAll();
   this.save(listofObject);
   this.flush();
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The entity must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entity must not be null!
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
```

Methods from class `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`methods from libririe

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAll() {
    for (T element : findAll()) {
      delete(element);
   }
}

@Transactional
 public void delete(T entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
    em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
}
```

I don't understand why findAll() returns list with null object, any help please

Comment: check what `findAll()` method returning if you call outside the `deleteAll()` method

Comment: Can you explain why you can‘t use the Standard jpa queries?

Comment: the problem is solved, there is an empty row in the table, which caused the problem